# All Possible ways Of Generics Identifier to Methods when Method Argument are <T> Or <?> or any?

Tags: java, list, generics, type-safety, typesafe

Not **new** to `java` but You may consider **Me** as **new** to **Generics** and having through various Confusion such that

> **A)** Is It necessary to add generics identifier to Method **IF** Method contains any **argument** like `myMethod(List <T> prm_ObjT, List<? extends Object>)` Or Any Such type of **Arguments** .

I Have tried this example to learn this Concept. And write multiple Variety of this Method

1. `public static void test(List<T> set)`

   **Error** : `cannot find symbol T :- public static void test(List<T> set)`
2. `public static <T extends Object> void test(List<T> list)  // Works Fine to me`
3. `public static <T> void test(List<T> list) // Works Again fine to me`
4. `public static <? extends Object>void test(List<?> set)`

   **Error** : `error: <identifier> expected
   public static <? extends Object>void test(List<?> set)`

   ```
   class Ideone
      {
   private static List<String> obj_larr= new ArrayList<String>();
        static {
   obj_larr.add("Vikrant");
   obj_larr.add("Nakul");
   obj_larr.add("Vishwas");
   obj_larr.add("Neeraj");
   obj_larr.add("Wahid");
        }

    public static <T extends Object> void test(List<T> list){ //Works Fine To me.
   System.out.println(list);
    }

   public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
     {
   test(obj_larr);
     }
   }
   ```

> Question :- Please explain each Situation and Provide all possible Combination of Identifier that can attach with a `Method()` If Method Generic Argument is passed in different ways ..?

Comment: 1) If you use a generic placeholder, you have to define it first; 4) you can not use the wildcard ? as the name of a generic placeholder.

Comment: why should close this??? please put your comments too why.. I have confusion and simply put the question .. I have tried so many variety but still a lot of Confusion..

Comment: Note that `public static void test(List<?> list){` would work fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Java Generics are confusing and somewhat illusive. There is also some terminology that one needs to use precisely. Usually, applying first principles works, but there are some hairy cases where the *line noise* in the Java source code becomes rather too much. Fortunately, your confusion is in understandable parts of Java Generics.

First of all, all your questions are with respect to generic methods. In Java, you have both generic classes and generic methods. The thing of (generic) essence here is the so called *type parameter*. The weird looking things enclosed inside `<>` are called type parameters.

The usefulness of *generic methods* is evident when you have a particular case at hand. My favorite example of this is from the JDK library itself, in the `java.util.Arrays` class:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

Here, the generic method is taking a variable list of arguments of *any type* and returning an `ArrayList` containing those elements. An **invocation** of this method is:

```
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
```

or

```
List<String> myFriends = Arrays.asList("Larry", "Moe", "Curly");
```

See how generic definition of `Arrays.asList` helps here, the compiler is able to assign `Integer` to the type parameter `T` in the first case, whereas `String` in another case!

Understanding generics using concrete examples (rather than contrived examples you cite) like the above helps.

There's a lot going on here, but one way to explain this is to look at it from a compiler's standpoint. Here's an attempt to explain why compilation succeeds or fails in the cases you have cited:

1. When it tries to compile a method like `public static void test(List<T> set)`, it gathers that it is a `static` method that takes a `List` of some type parameter `T`. But what is `T`? Compiler wants you to specify that it is a generic type parameter (let's say it's just the "syntax" of generic method declaration). That's what you do when you say `public static <T> void test(List<T> set)` and compiler is happy.
2. In the second declaration, you do specify that and compiler is happy. It's important to note that like any other `Object` in Java, the type parameter itself also needs to be an `Object` and like (when your class is just a `java.lang.Object`) you *don't* have to specify `public class MyClass extends Object`, you don't have to specify that `T extends Object` if that's the only restriction you have. So, `public static <T extends Object> void test(List<T> list)` is equivalent to `public static <T> void test(List<T> list)`. You might argue why `<T>` is needed in the generic method declaration, but you may read the [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4) for details, since the devil is in the details here.
3. As we said above in 2), 2) and 3) are equivalent.
4. The type parameter, if specified, must have a `name`. In this declaration you are considering the so-called *wild-card* and that complicates things further. But leaving that aside, like the compiler is complaining, it does not find the generic type declaration in your method declaration valid because it wants to know the `name` (or, `identifier`) for the type parameter.

Comment: Actually I didn't get your Fourth answer completely and I have also asked about all Possible Combination Of `Method Identifier` and `Argument Type` which could use with a generic Method.

Comment: I have explored so many Internet sources but Confusion still Resides. Thanks

Comment: I guess it suffices to say that if you want to _specify_ a type parameter in the method declaration, then you have got to provide a _name_ or an _identifier_ for it, just like a variable or a method parameter needs a name. To improve the understanding, perhaps you should consider referring to a slightly older, but well-written book: "Java Generics" by Naftalin/Wadler.

Comment: sorry i didn't like the content of O`Really. I have read many books of this publication but I didn't like it Better to go with oracle Docs

Answer (score 0):

I am not good at generic either. Here is my way to remember the syntax:

1. When using the generic type `T` in a method, it can be a parameter or a return type. So you will have to declare it before the return type.
2. The wildcard `?` means we don't care about the type, so you use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a complete treatment of type calculus *(why the type system is mathematically sound)* in Benjamin Pierce's excellent book *Types and Programming Languages* (TAPL).

1. An important first thing to understand is that *type variables* name **types**, which in Java are always represented as **classes**.

### Before Generics

Using your method signature, let's consider what it looked like *before generics in Java*: `public static void test(List list)`. That shouldn't be confusing at all.

However, note that the "naked" `List` can hold any objects at all. A more precise way to say that: *it can hold any subclass of `Object` and we have no way of constraining types added to the list*, e.g., a list containing both an Integer and a String.

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("hello world!");
list.add(new Integer(1));
test(list);
```

That's perfectly legal Java syntax, even today (with compiler warnings). But notice that the `test` method must handle any possible type provided inside the list.

What's needed is a way to *constrain* the types that can be placed into the list and have the compiler enforce that to the best of its ability.

### Generically

We can use the syntax `public static void test(List<Object> list)` to represent the same thing, but we still haven't constrained the values of the list.

#### Type Constants and Type Variables

Notice above where we specified `List<Object>`, that `Object` is a *type constant*. The only thing it describes is instances of the exact type `Object` and that's really all we can know about items the list contains.

What we need is a way to specify an *unknown type* when the `List` class is being compiled. There's no way that the JDK, which implements the `List` class, can know at its compile time what you might want to put in it.

Furthermore, we need more flexibility than that. We'd like to be able to specify type constraints in 3 different flavors:

- *some type that we'll name `T`, exactly* (a.k.a. *invariant*), with syntax `<T>`;
- *some type that we'll name `T` and all of its subtypes* (a.k.a. *covariant*), with syntax `<? extends T>`;
- *some type that we'll name `T` and all of its supertypes* (a.k.a. *contravariant*), with syntax `<? super T>`.

That's where *type variables* come from. They represent *unknown types* at compile time, just as normal variables represent *unknown values* at compile time.

In order to get all 3 constraint flavors, the compiler treats type variables for Java **methods** using the syntax above. You cannot use the second or third syntax for generic variable declarations *(a `List<Number>` can hold values of type `Number` or any of its subclasses without extra syntax)*.

> Note that in the type calculus presented in TAPL, `T` is both the first subtype of itself, and also the first supertype of itself. So saying `? extends T` or `? super T` implicitly includes `T` itself.
>
> More on type variance at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)

### Back to Your Examples

1. `public static void test(List<T> set)` fails because the compiler is looking for a type (class named `T`), which isn't defined anywhere.
2. `public static <T extends Object> void test(List<T> list)` is correct syntax but more verbose than it needs to be. Idiomatically, it's the same as
3. `public static <T> void test(List<T> list)`

   Here, the `test` method still receives values of type `Object`, because there's no further constraint on `T`.
4. `public static <? extends Object> void test(List<?> set)` fails because `?` is not a valid type variable name (same restrictions as for Java class names).

   `public static void test(List<?> set)` works just fine.

### Notes

1. In Java, generics are only a feature of the **compiler**. There were no JVM changes. Therefore the bytecode method signatures still use `Object`, and the compiler emits cast instructions where needed.
2. Because of (1), you have to consider *type erasure*, but that's another question for another day.